# Can't ssh into a hadoop node

Tags: 10.10, installation, hadoop

All right folks, I have another very basic question. Please bear with me.

I'm following the instructions at the following website to download and configure Hadoop on my computer.

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

I'm at the final SSH section, when I use the localhost command. When I run the following code, I get an error message.

```
hadoop@amathew-Dimension-3000:~$ cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
hadoop@amathew-Dimension-3000:~$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Here's some other information which might be relevant.

```
hadoop@amathew-Dimension-3000:~$ ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu5, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ::1 port 22: Connection refused
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Can anyone help?

Once again, thanks for helping the newbie who just can't figure things out yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that your SSH process is not running. Therefore there is no software which accepts connections on that port. You can check it by:

```
sudo service ssh status
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh status
```

The script should output something like `ssh start/running, process 1234` if SSH is running. If not, you'll see `ssh stop/waiting`. I suspect you'll get the last message. If this is the case, you just should start your SSH daemon by:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

Furthermore you should have a look in you `sshd_config` and in `/etc/default/ssh` if there are some "strange" options.

Comment: Turns out I didn't have an openSSH client installed. I installed it and reran the commands and things are fixed.